# Syslog filling up with "radeon crtc page flip" only on Ubuntu 16.04 Unity Desktop

Tags: unity, 16.04, kernel, radeon, syslog

I'm having this issue when trying to run Ubuntu 16.04 and logging in to the Unity Desktop. I'm getting megabytes in minutes into the syslog file. Unity appears to be working correctly, however if left alone long enough, the disk starts to fill up with syslog radeon_crtc_page_flip entries. That prevents the use of Unity. The **issue doesn't occur** with Gnome Metacity or Compiz. The log indicates as follows:

```
...
Sep  6 23:56:30 xxxxx kernel: [288139.440746] [drm:radeon_crtc_page_flip] flip-ioctl() cur_rbo = ffff880072b3a800, new_rbo = ffff88007478cc00
Sep  6 23:56:30 xxxxx kernel: [288139.507438] [drm:drm_mode_addfb2] [FB:42]
Sep  6 23:56:30 xxxxx kernel: [288139.507479] [drm:radeon_crtc_page_flip] flip-ioctl() cur_rbo = ffff88007478cc00, new_rbo = ffff880072b3a800
Sep  6 23:56:30 xxxxx kernel: [288139.574415] [drm:drm_mode_addfb2] [FB:52]
Sep  6 23:56:30 xxxxx kernel: [288139.574456] [drm:radeon_crtc_page_flip] flip-ioctl() cur_rbo = ffff880072b3a800, new_rbo = ffff88007478cc00
Sep  6 23:56:30 xxxxx kernel: [288139.640800] [drm:drm_mode_addfb2] [FB:42]
Sep  6 23:56:30 xxxxx kernel: [288139.640835] [drm:radeon_crtc_page_flip] flip-ioctl() cur_rbo = ffff88007478cc00, new_rbo = ffff880072b3a800
Sep  6 23:56:30 xxxxx kernel: [288139.707432] [drm:drm_mode_addfb2] [FB:52]
...
```

As can be seen, some of the entries are less than 50 usec apart.

**lspci:**
...
`01:05.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] RS480 [Radeon Xpress 200 Series]`
...

Any help would be appreciated, because Unity is an excellent Desktop interface...

Comment: I am having similar outputs in my syslog:

Oct 30 15:22:38 localhost kernel: [  269.246641] [drm:drm_mode_addfb2] [FB:56]
Oct 30 15:22:38 localhost kernel: [  269.280203] [drm:drm_mode_addfb2] [FB:57]
Oct 30 15:22:38 localhost kernel: [  269.314189] [drm:drm_mode_addfb2] [FB:56]
Oct 30 15:22:38 localhost kernel: [  269.346729] [drm:drm_mode_addfb2] [FB:57]
Oct 30 15:22:38 localhost kernel: [  269.380520] [drm:drm_mode_addfb2] [FB:56]
Oct 30 15:22:38 localhost kernel: [  269.413687] [drm:drm_mode_addfb2] [FB:57]